# Java Client working with two servers

Tags: java, server, client

I´m trying to do a client that reads data from two servers simultaneously, for example, the client sends a string to both servers that capitalize it and then sends it back to the client.

Client Side

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     Connection c1 = new Connection("localhost", 2345, "example one");
     c1.start();

     Connection c2 = new Connection("localhost", 2346, "example two");
     c2.start();
```

Server side

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

private String host;
private int port;
private PrintWriter os;
private volatile boolean running = false;
private String stringToCap;

public Connection(String host, int port, String stringToCap) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.stringToCap = stringToCap;
}

public void start() {
    try {
        this.os = new PrintWriter(new Socket(host, port).getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }

    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();

@Override
public void run() {

    while(running) {
    stringToCap.toUpperCase();

            os.print(stringToCap);


        }}
```

But I cant seem to get the server to print back the now capitalized string to the client. When I try the above I get nothing, Do I need a main method on the server side too?

Comment: Maybe you are getting an IOException inside your try catch. Try printing the error via e.printStackTrace().

Comment: You don't have a server. The Connection class is a Client and connects to an existing server. Where is your server? Please read more about socket programming here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a misconception.

Your current code is just a multi-thread application with 2 threads called `Connection` and not a true Client and Server application.

Please refer to the [Java Tutorial, Custom Networking section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html).